# Criar div entre outras ao invés de no final com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Consegui criar a nova `div` no final da `div` com id `pai` com `.appendChild`:

```html
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho1">texto qualquer 1</div>
    <div id="filho2">texto qualquer 2</div>
    <div id="filho3">texto qualquer 3</div>
</div>
<script>
    var nova_div = document.createElement('div');
    nova_div.innerText = 'NOVA DIV';
    document.getElementById('pai').appendChild(nova_div);
</script>
```

Mas queria ela no meio das outras `div`, ao invés de no final.

Exemplo:

```
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho1">texto qualquer 1</div>
    <div id="filho2">texto qualquer 2</div>
    <div>NOVA DIV</div>
    <div id="filho3">texto qualquer 3</div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer?

Comment: O [prepend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) faz o que você precisa. No link tem um polyfill para IE.

Comment: Tentei com essa função, mas ela vai pro final igual appendChild e eu quero entre. Mas ja consegui com a função do Sam vlw!!

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o `.insertBefore()`. Ele insere um novo elemento antes de um determinado elemento dentro de um pai. Exemplo:

```js
var nova_div = document.createElement('div');
nova_div.innerText = 'NOVA DIV';
var pai = document.getElementById('pai');
pai.insertBefore(nova_div, pai.querySelector("#filho3"));
```

```html
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho1">texto qualquer 1</div>
    <div id="filho2">texto qualquer 2</div>
    <div id="filho3">texto qualquer 3</div>
</div>
```

Eu selecionei a `div#filho3` com `.querySelector` e inseri a nova div antes dele.

Comment: Saquei, não conhecia essa função, vou usar ela mesmo ajudou muito!!!

Comment: Não deixe de marcar a resposta com ✔. Valeu!