# Colocar elemento no meio de HTML

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

É possível colocar um elemento, no meio de um código html? Exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte artigo que possui o html:

```html
<article>

  <p>texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto</p>

  <p>texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto</p>

  <h2>Título 1</h2>

  <p>texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto</p>

</article>
```

Vamos supor que eu queira inserir de forma automática sempre uma lista com alguns tópicos escritos logo após o segundo parágrafo em todos os artigos.

```
<ul>
  <li>elemento 1</li>
  <li>elemento 2</li>
  <li>elemento 2</li>
</ul>
```

Alguém tem um artigo, um link, ou possa me dar uma direção. Acredito que com Jquery é possível. No worpress tem plugins que fazem isso, mas é um projeto fora do WP.

Comment: não tem nada a ver com css e alinhamento. Inserir, por exemplo uma lista sempre após o segundo paragrafo, por exemplo.

Comment: imagina um artigo, tem o primeiro paragrafo, o segundo, o terceiro. Dado momento quero fazer uma chamada no meio do texto para outro pagina. Esse elemnto seria uma lista, como coloquei na pergunta, e que fique logo após o segundo paragrafo. Quero fazer isso de forma automática.

Comment: Possível duplicata: [Criar div entre outras ao invés de no final com JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369326/criar-div-entre-outras-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-no-final-com-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se é isso que entendi vc pode usar o método `.append` do jQuery para incluir um link depois do parágrafo que vc indique com um nome de classe, ou ID que for se vc preferir ou se tiver acesso ao HTML.

Ou então vc pode pegar o elemento usando `p:nth-child(N°)` ou `p:eq(n°)`

Com `:nth-child` é como se fosse o índice do CSS, e o primeiro `<p>` é = `1`
Com `:eq` é o índice do JS e o primeiro `<p>` é = `0`

Recomendo que leia essa documentação para ver como o `.append` pode propagar, ou não nos `<p>` dependendo de como vc o seleciona https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#example-1

Seria algo assim:

```html
<p>primeiro p</p>
<p>segundo  p</p>
<p>terceiro p</p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( "p:nth-child(2)" ).append( "<br><a href='#'>link do append nth-child</a>" );
  $( "p:eq(2)" ).append( "<br><a href='#'>link do append eq()</a>" );
</script>
```

Documentação oficial do jQuery http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: não daria, os artigos já estão escritos, não posso um a um inserir uma class, fica inviável. Teria que ser algo que percorra todo o texto, identifique o segundo parágrafo, ou o 3, ou o 4, etc... e insira qualquer coisa logo após. o plugin quick adsense por exemplo, faz isso no WP.

Comment: @Rod Já editei com duas outras formas de selecionar o `<p>` desejado, uma com `nth-child` e outra com `eq`

Comment: acho que é isso cara, vou testar aqui.

Comment: Foda cara. Simples e Perfeito.

Comment: @Rod  legal que resolveu

Comment: só uma ultima coisa, antes de algum elemento pego como em css? por exemplo, antes do segundo h3.

Comment: @Rod jovem to correndo aqui que já deu a hora de vazar da empresa, mas no css é a mesma coisa do nth-child, se a tag antes do segundo h3 é um span, e esse span é o primeiro da página vc usaria `span:nth-child(1) { seu css }` leia mais aqui o básico https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp vc ainda pode pegar com outrs seletores CSS tipo first-of-type, only-of-type etc, da uma procurada no Google que vai te ajudar mais que eu escrevendo aqui rss

Comment: valeu cara. muito obrigado.

Comment: aproveitando sua resposta, volto aqui para perguntar: É possoivel colocar um bloco do adsense, que é um javscript, dentro desse append, ou algo similar?

Comment: @Rod daria sim para "injetar" um script na página depois que ela carregar, mas o do AdSense eu não recomendaria fazer isso, pois o Bot do Google lê a página na requisição , não sei se ele vai esperar a pagina carregar inteira e depois escanear novamente para ver se algum script carregou algo a mais. De uma lida nessa outra resposta lá é com Meta Tag, Mas com o Script do AdSense seria a mesma coisa acredito https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406120/alterar-as-meta-tags-no-carregamento-afeta-no-rankeamento/406128#406128

Comment: to quase perto de uma solução. Mudei tudo, estou tentando fazer isso com regex e replace no asp. Falta só um detalhe, por favor, se puder ajudar. Como faço em regex para pegar a terceira ocorrência do mesmo caracter em um texto?  exemplo de texto: <p>paragrafo 1</p><p>paragrafo 2</p><p>paragrafo 3</p>. Queria conseguir pegar o segundo "</p>", aí vou substituir pelo bloco de anuncio.

Comment: @Rod cara meu conhecimento de Regex é 0, infelizmente não consigo te ajudar nessa... Se for possível adicione um ID nesse segundo P, ai fica mais fácil para vc usa-lo como seletor... Em último caso abre uma nova pergunta, coloca todo seu código e explique direitinho que sempre tem alguém para ajudar

Comment: Valeu meu camarada. Te agradeço muito. Abri uma questão nova, deve ser algo simples.

Answer (score 0):

É possível só que você ter que nomear os elementos HTML com a tag `id`, da seguinte forma:

```js
var $wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
    HTMLTemporario = $wrapper.innerHTML,
    HTMLNovo = 'Teste prepend com innerHTML </br>';
HTMLTemporario = HTMLNovo + HTMLTemporario;
$wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLTemporario;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">Conteúdo</div>
```

Comment: estou tentando entender aqui. vai inserir no inicio né.

Comment: @Rod Na verdade a ordem quem defini é você, observe essa parte `HTMLTemporario = HTMLNovo + HTMLTemporario;`, veja que o novo vem primeiro !

Comment: Caso você queira que o conteúdo HTML venha antes, basta você inverter a ordem `HTMLTemporario = HTMLTemporario + HTMLNovo;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contentUl = `<ul>
  <li>elemento 1</li>
  <li>elemento 2</li>
  <li>elemento 2</li>
</ul>`;


  $("body article").each(function(index) {
   if(index > 1){
    $($(this)).append(contentUl);
   }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <article>
    <p>texto...</p>
    <h2>Título 1</h2>
  </article>
  <article>
    <p>texto2...</p>
    <h2>Título 2</h2>
  </article>
  <article>
    <p>texto3...</p>
    <h2>Título 3</h2>
  </article>
  <article>
    <p>texto4...</p>
    <h2>Título 4</h2>
  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: os textos já estão prontos e são muitos fica inviavel ter que inserir <div class='jsContentTwoP'></div> em todos eles.

Comment: por isso pensei, se conseguir percorrer o texto e identificar por exemplo o 3 paragrafo e inserir qualquer coisa apos ele.

Comment: Editei o codigo, Se eu não entendi mal, você quer isso?