# Alterar as meta-tags no carregamento afeta no rankeamento?

Tags: php, html5, google, seo

Bom dia !!

Pessoal, eu tenho um site onde a estrutura é feita com chamadas *PHP* no topo, corpo e rodapé.

Com base na rota que o usuário entra (por exemplo *www.site.com/artigo/artigo-exemplo-1*) eu quero alterar dinamicamente as *meta-tags* com `JS`.

Isso vai afetar no rankeamento? As *meta-tags* que inseri dinamicamente serão consideradas pelo motor de busca?

Exemplo estrutura:
index.php

```html
<html>
    <head>....</head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include_once("menu.php");
        include_once("corpo.php");//Aqui temos o tratamento da rota
        include_once("rodape.php");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente vc não vai ter problemas. Mas o ideal mesmo é que vc monitore como o Google realmente está encontrando seu conteúdo, para isso vc pode usar a ferramenta do Google Search Console https://search.google.com

Já em 2012 se sabia que o `crawler` do Google era capaz de entender algum script, e mesmo Ajax. Recomendo que leia esse artigo com um estudo que fizerem mudando a tag `<title>` e injetando um conteúdo com `.innerHTML`. Vc vai ver que o bot encontrou facilmente o conteúdo dinâmico inclusive testarm um componente de Abas e tudo foi indexado. https://moz.com/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really

No caso do PHP seria ainda melhor, pois o build seria no serverside, antes de entregar o conteúdo já montado, o que acredito facilitaria ainda mais a indexação do bot do Google.

E de acordo com esse artigo do próprio Google vc pode ver que:

> ... In order to solve this problem, we decided to try to understand pages by executing JavaScript.

- Recomendamos que permita que o Googlebot recupere JavaScript e CSS para que seu conteúdo possa ser melhor indexado. Isso é especialmente importante para websites para dispositivos móveis, onde recursos externos, como CSS e JavaScript, ajudam nossos algoritmos a entender que as páginas são otimizadas para dispositivos móveis.
- Às vezes, o JavaScript pode ser muito complexo ou misterioso para ser executado, caso em que não podemos renderizar a página de forma completa e precisa.
- Alguns JavaScript remove o conteúdo da página em vez de adicionar, o que nos impede de indexar o conteúdo.

**OBS:** Aparentemente o Google tb escaneia o CSS, e incusive vc pode ver análises disso pelo LightHouse do DevTools

*Fonte:* https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

**OBS2:** Um fato interessante e que talvez comprove de fato que o Google entende script é o uso comum do JSON-LD que é usado para marcar dados estruturados e é lido pelo crawler facilmente, artigo sobre isso https://medium.com/@rogeralbino/marcando-dados-com-json-ld-3d893408e530

Comment: Excelente sugestão sobre o JSON-LD, eu não conhecia!
Vou fazer alguns testes com o google search para ter certeza se indexou corretamente, nao havia pensado nisso

Comment: @MarcusVinicius sem problemas, espero que ajude, se vc lembrar depois volta aqui para comentar os resultados ;D