# Por que devemos usar HTML 5 em vez de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de utilizarmos HTML 5 em vez de JavaScript? Sendo que, no JavaScript conseguimos fazer tudo que o HTML 5 consegue fazer, porém o oposto não acontece...

Referências: [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/HTML5),[Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/JavaScript), [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM)

Comment: Para aqueles que votaram -1, poderiam esclarecer o que viram de errado na pergunta e como sugeririam melhorá-la?

Comment: Mas aproveitando, Rodrigo, poderia dar exemplos do que seria o "tudo que o HTML 5 consegue fazer" que o JavaScript também faz?

Comment: A pergunta está ampla de mais e não está clara. Na verdade nem deu para entender direito o que o AP quer dizer como "o que faço em um consigo fazer no outro"... O que ele faz em um e não faz no outro? Ao que vc se refere?

Comment: Eu respondi porque achei a pergunta compreensível, ainda que partindo de uma premissa falha (em geral quem está aprendendo comete esse erro). Ele quer saber porque não usamos só JS, até porque dá para fazer isto. Por que existe o HTML se podemos montar páginas só escrevendo código JS. Em vez de criar um `<div>`, pode escrever um código crie uma divisão no DOM, pode preencher o conteúdo dela, tudo com JS e mais nada. O mesmo poderia ser dito de CSS. Um dúvida bastante pertinente que permite uma explicação simples (eu gosto de detalhar, mas pode seer feito em dois parágrafos pequenos)..

Comment: O HTML é forma básica de manipular o DOM e ela tem bastante limitação, em geral só criando os nós e atribuindo um valor para ele e preenchendo seus atributos. O JS permite manipular de forma muito mais flexível e poderosa.

Comment: Um exemplo de como carregar um JS sem HTML nenhum seria bom pra sustentar a tese.

Comment: Resumindo, o HTML preenche o DOM inicialmente, e o JS manipula dinamicamente. São coisas relacionadas, e não concorrentes. Eu sinceramente acho que o post deveria ser fechado por partir de premissas equivocadas, além de falta de clareza e ainda um componente de opinião. Pra piorar, é uma área que a maior parte que usa não sabe o que está fazendo, então tende a virar um caos. A "sorte" é que as duas primeiras respostas não foram de paraquedista, como anda acontecendo bastante no site..

Answer (score 2):

## Entendendo o DOM e a relação entre HTML e JavaScript

Já existem algumas perguntas sobre o DOM:

- [O que é DOM, Render Tree e Node?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101)
- [O que é parse, e como funciona o parse do DOM no HTML5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99632/101)

Isto é o que importa para o navegador renderizar o conteúdo. Existe uma forma básica simples que o manipula que é o HTML. Podemos dizer, grosso modo, que ele é a API declarativa básica para isto (falo mais abaixo).

Existem outras APIs que fazem o mesmo, uma delas é o CSS que é tão importante também (não vou falar que ele é tão simples porque há muita confusão na sua concepção), mas existem outras que muitos até não entendem que são coisas distintas, mas que também servem para manipular o DOM.

O JavaScript é uma linguagem de programação, portanto é mais imperativa e permite fazer muito mais operações, e como tem uma API para manipular o DOM em sua biblioteca padrão nos navegadores é possível fazer operações muito mais poderosas nessa manipulação de DOM.

Em essência você pode fazer tudo no JS até [por ser uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101). Uma linguagem de marcação (HTML) ou estilização (CSS) não podem fazer tudo (até conseguiram juntar as duas e fazer coisas mais complexas, mas de uma forma maluca, não dá para usar de verdade assim).

## Obrigação de usar HTML5

Ninguém ou alguma coisa te obriga a usar o HTML, 5 ou não, você de fato pode fazer tudo com JS, e eu até gosto da "ideia". Até pode ser que a carga dos *scripts* dependam ligeiramente do HTML, mas só.

Se você se sente mais confortável com JavaScript, não gosta de HTML e considera que pode fazer melhor sem usá-lo deixar tudo para o JS pode fazer se for uma aplicação. Não estou recomendando, mas dizendo que é possível.

## *Websites*

Se for um site complica um pouco porque os mecanismos de buscas terão dificuldades de indexar o conteúdo do seu site e ele não será achado pelas pessoas. Deseja ou aceita isto?

Há um mito que esses mecanismos entendem JS, mas ele não consegue executar tudo como aconteceria com a ação de um humano, então pode até conseguir indexar o conteúdo de alguma forma, mas não tudo, não corretamente. Não tem como mesmo com os *bots* modernos que entendem JS simular toda ação e recriar o que um humano faria.

Além disso alguns navegadores podem ser antigos ou ter algumas coisas desabilitadas, por exemplo o JS todo, o que faria suas páginas não acontecerem. Quer isto?

## Tipo de profissional

Fora isto basicamente é gosto mesmo. *Designers* tendem a ter mais facilidade com HTML que é uma linguagem de marcação e mais fácil de entender do que com JS.

Algumas pessoas aprendem bem HTML mas JS nem tanto. É comum ver todo mundo fazendo tudo o que dá com HTML e só vai para o JS quando não tem outro jeito, aí outras pessoas copiam essas, então todo mundo aprende mais HTML que JS, é meio viral, tem mais informação ensinando usar HTML prioritariamente para depois ir para o JS. Tudo isso influencia como as pessoas adotam tecnologias.

Não dá para falar em vantagem ou desvantagem clara, tem uma ou outra de acordo com o *background* de cada um, e o que eu falei, se todo mundo usa o HTML 5 pode ter ajuda de forma mais fácil, ter mais exemplos, mais receitas para seguir, ou por ser mais intuitivo para certas pessoas (o JS é mais intuitivo pra mim, mas a API fraca dele faz eu pensar em usar o HTML, mesmo ele permitindo fazer tudo).

[image: carro transportando um cavalo no banco de trás que está com a cabeça pra fora da janela]

Dá para usar só o JS, mas tem a ferramenta certa para cada momento. Alguns querem usar só o JS para não ter que aprender o HTML. O HTML não é difícil, manipular o DOM é que é, isso não tem como fugir, você fará com JS, HTML, CSS e outras APIs.

## Simplicidade

Ainda podemos dizer que em certo cenário é um pouco mais fácil desenhar a página através do HTML. A a característica não posicional do conteúdo favorece uma forma declarativa um pouco mais que a forma imperativa do JS.

Pode ser muito mais simples e ter um código mais curto para fazer páginas muito simples (em geral não muito dinâmicas). E para as complexas pode diminuir um pouco a complexidade, até porque poucas pessoas sabem organizar código JS para produzir o mesmo resultado.

É muito mais intuitivo fazer certas coisas no HTML do que criar o mesmo efeito com JS. Grosso modo, podemos entender (não que seja bem isso) que o HTML meio que são funções prontas que fazem algumas coisas. Possuem alguma parametrização (os atributos), mas é limitado.

Limitação ajuda ser mais fácil. Por isso que as pessoas preferem fazer o mais fácil primeiro (a carga inicial do conteúdo) e quando precisa do poder vai para a tecnologia que permite isto, o JS. Um ajuda o outro.

Não que eu concorde muito com a forma como está acontecendo, mas está cada vez mais comum em aplicações as pessoas quase abandonarem o HTML, até por usarem componentes de *frameworks* que geral isto para ela. Não que não tenha de HTML, mas tem menos que tinha antes. Por outro lado, estão usando esses web componentes como se fossem HTML nativo (estou falando de Angular, React, Vue e outros, que são JS).

Comment: Na minha leitura, essa pergunta indica uma falha meio que fundamental de entendimento do que é HTML e do que é Javascript - já que você se deu ao trabalho de responder, talvez pudesse abordar isso nos primeiros parágrafos.

Comment: Sim, por isso ele perguntou. Eu cheguei fechar a pergunta porque a premissa estava ruim, mas aí percebi que era justamente por ele não entender isso é que ela deveria ser respondida.

Comment: Maniero sobre o SEO esse vídeo deve te interessar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pOH8Smd0Xs está fresquinho é do Chrome Dev Summit que aconteceu esse mês. Sei que o Google não é único, mas considerando que é o mecanismo de busca de mais de 90% dos brasileiros, acredito que tenha mais força no mercado SEO...

Comment: @hugocsl se estiver falando que o Google entende o JS isso é sempre uma mentira, ele entende, mas ele não pode simular as ações que o usuário faria. Se você souvber fazewr muito bem, não ter como o Google se enganar pode até dar certo, mas as pessoas nem tem noção disto, até porque elas acreditam que é só por o JS lá e tudo ficará perfeito. É muito difícil fazer ficar bom, não por acaso hoje o tal do [SSR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411529/101) faz tanto sucesso, pri8ncipalmente pra mandar pra Google.

Comment: Vou aproveitar para pedir *feedback* sobre o problema da resposta, só o jsbueno falou algo, embora eu não entendi porque isso mereça um negativo, o problema pode ser na pergunta, mas talvez nem seja, conforme o Woss questionou. Eu respondi exatamente o que ele perguntou e apontei o entendimento errado que o AP tm do assunto. Se o problema for outro então me informe para ver se eu corrijo ou se eu respondo sobre o erro que a pessoa tem sobre o assunto que o levou a negativar, assim todos ganhamos.

Comment: De qualquer forma tentei dar uma melhorada pra ficar mais claro, quem sabe alguém ache que agora não mereça negativo mais.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 não é uma tecnologia alternativa ao JavaScript, ele é um DOCTYPE, como expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209599/3635

Mas também é um termo usado por certos desenvolvedores (do qual eu discordei muito até desistir de debater) para se referenciar a diversas tecnologias que vieram na mesma época que o HTML5 começou a ser suportado por diversos navegadores, como exemplo:

- Novas APIs nativas para JavaScript
- Novas funcionalidade CSS (principalmente as que são usadas com tags especificas do HTML, como `--webkit-progress-bar` para `<progressbar>`, sendo ou não padronizado)
- Canvas (apesar deste ser suportado por alguns navegadores antes do HTML5)

Então muitas vezes as pessoas usam html5 para se referenciar ao que não é HTML5, aqui no site a tag é muito usada com este intuito:

- [html5](/questions/tagged/html5)

Se olhar as perguntas vai notar que muitas delas são perguntas sobre CSS e JavaScript e não sobre as tags do HTML5 e seus comportamentos.

Eu pessoalmente acho muito errado essa maneira de se "referir" as tecnologias, porque pra mim que busquei aprender do básico e não só viver de ctrl+c como muitos desenvolvedores fazem (em diversas comunidades, nacionais e gringas), isso sempre soa estranho, me parecia no começo (talvez ainda soe assim) que na verdade os devs nem sabiam direito do que estavam falando e geralmente nem entendiam o básico de doctype

---

### Respondendo "HTML 5 em vez de JavaScript"

Quase todas tags HTML5 que tem funcionalidades "extras" que vieram com o HTML5 tem API de comunicação ou eventos que podem ser "ouvidos" via JavaScript, logo o HTML5 é a *linguagem de marcação*+*novas funcionalidades* e o JavaScript é *"linguagem de programação"* que pode trabalhar essas novas funcionalidades de cada tag, por exemplo se pegar a tags `<audio id="bar">` ou `<video id="foo">` pode parar a musica ou o video tocado via JavaScript:

```
function pararAudio()
{
     var bar = document.getElementById('bar');

     if (bar) bar.stop();
}

function pararVideo()
{
     var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

     if (foo) foo.stop();
}
```

Então simplesmente HTML5 são essas tags e as tags que já existiam antes, mas as pessoas se referencia desta forma "errônea" (em minha opinião) para dizer que HTML5 é tudo o que já foi citado no começo da resposta.

HTML5 sozinho não tem a capacidade de controlar de forma "programada" o que deseja, por exemplo, criar novas tags, vai ter gente que vai citar coisas absurdas como:

> Mas e o Vue.js?
>
> Mas e o Angular?
>
> Mas e o React?

Como se eles realmente gerassem novas tags de forma stand-alone, mas na verdade esses "frameworks" não são HTML5, eles são uma série de libs e estrutura que usam HTML5 e JavaScript (sendo que possuem linguagens próprias que são [**"transpiladas"**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/3635) para JavaScript e HTML)